# Use Others Hard disk space in my system connected in a network

Tags: networking, windows-10, disk-space, disk-utility

In my office we are having around 60 systems running with windows 10 with specs: Intel I5 processor,1tb hdd etc. in almost all the systems around 500gb diskspace is idle and no one is utilising now i would like to map all the remaining idle drives to my pc.  is it possible ?
Please do the needful.

Comment: Do you have access to a very large supply of aspirin, because that would be the biggest headache ever. A logistical nightmare waiting at every possible opportunity to come back & bite you.